# The correct usage?

Tags: usage

I want <strike>to</strike> my friend to choose the right people in her life. Which one of these sentences should I use ? Be around the right people or be around with the right people ?

Comment: But while Google Books Ngram Viewer shows multiple uses of **be around people** it shows none of **be around with people** - if that helps you choose. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+around+people%2Cbe+around+with+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20around%20people%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

"Be around the right people" is correct if not very idiomatic. Perhaps "Don't hang out with the wrong people" would be better?

But it really doesn't matter since if you are having a *heart-to-heart* discussion with a *friend* about *their life choices*, nobody is going to start picking apart your use of prepositions.

Can you imagine the following dialog?

> — Be around with the right people.
>   — I know you want to help me, and I do love you as a friend, but I'm going to ignore what you say because you put the word "with" after "around".